# How use a dynamic array with a structure

Tags: c, sorting, struct, heapsort

I have written a program for heap sort and I tried to have both the array and the size of the array in a single structure but there seems to be some error in my code (I think it's in the initializing part).
Here is my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int cmp;

typedef struct heap
{
    int *arr, n;
}heap;

void main()
{
    heap *h;
    scanf("%d",&h->n);
    h->arr = (int*)malloc(h->n*sizeof(int));
    
    for(int i=0; i<h->n; i++)
        scanf("%d",h->arr+i);
    
    build_heap(h);
    heap_sort(h);
    
    for(int i=0; i<h->n; i++)
        printf("%d ",h->arr[i]);
    printf("\n%d\n",cmp);
    free(h->arr);

}
```

I compiled it in linux platform and the error I got was  `Segmentation fault (core dumped) Can someone explain why I got this error and give a possible solution to this.`

Comment: Using `h->n` and `h->arr` directly after declaring `h` as an uninitialised `heap *` cannot be correct. Instead, declare `h` as a `heap` and use `h.n` and `h.arr`. Remember that `h->n` is nothing more than a synonym for `(*h).n`, and using the `*` operator on an uninitialised pointer will result in a segmentation fault at best.

Answer (score 3):

By doing this `heap *h;` you have declared a pointer to a heap struct, but what does this pointer actually point to at this point?

You only need to allocate the memory for your heap:

```c
void main()
{
    heap *h;
    // Alloc and initialize the pointer to the heap
    h = malloc(sizeof(heap));
    scanf("%d",&h->n);
    h->arr = malloc(h->n*sizeof(int));
    
    for(int i=0; i<h->n; i++)
        scanf("%d",h->arr+i);
    
    build_heap(h);
    heap_sort(h);
    
    for(int i=0; i<h->n; i++)
        printf("%d ",h->arr[i]);
    printf("\n%d\n",cmp);
    free(h->arr);

    // Don't forget to free the heap as well!
    free(h);

}
```

Also, it is a good practice to not cast the return value of `malloc`.

Answer (score 1):

Do it a bit different way:

```
typedef struct heap
{
    size_t n;
    int arr[]; 
}heap;
```

only one `malloc` and `free` is needed.

```
    size_t size;
    heap *h;

    if(scanf("%zu", &size) != 1) { /* error handling*/};
    h = malloc(sizeof(*h) + size * sizeof(h -> arr[0]));
    if(!h) { /* error handling*/};
    h -> size = size;

    /*...... */


    free(h);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you declare `heap *h;` you declare a pointer, but after you never initialize `h` to point anywhere.

You probably want this:

```
int main()
{
  heap h;                              // now h is a heap and no more a pointer to heap
  scanf("%d", &h.n);
  h.arr = malloc(h.n * sizeof(int));   // the cast to (int*) is useless

  for (int i = 0; i < h.n; i++)
    scanf("%d", h.arr + i);            //BTW: &h.arr[i] would be more readable

  build_heap(&h);
  heap_sort(&h);

  for (int i = 0; i < h.n; i++)
    printf("%d ", h.arr[i]);

  printf("\n%d\n", cmp);
  free(h.arr);
}
```

There may be more problems in `build_heap` and in `build_heap`, but I can't tell you more as you didn't show these functions.